# Intuition (and name) of this result about bivariate expected values?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value, bivariate-distributions

I've seen the following result about expected values in class:

> $$E(g(X,Y))=\int_{\mathbb{R}} E(g(X,y)|Y=y)f_Y (y) \ dy $$
>   Where $ E(g(X,y)|Y=y)= \int_\mathbb{R}g(x,y)f_{X|Y}(x|y) \  dx $.
>   (I'm not sure if this comes directly from the definition of $E(g(X)|Y=y)?$ Can we just treat the $y$ as a constant?)

I was wondering whether anyone could explain why this is "intuitively true"? Is it to do with the law of total probability? Is there a name for this result?

The reasoning I've tried/heard: "We "fix" a value of $Y=y$, and calculate the expectation given assuming this is true, and then times this by the "density" and sum over all possible $y$ values.

I was a little dissatisfied with this explanation because it seems to just be describing the integral. But, I might have missed something in the explanation which made it less intuitive for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a name for this result?

The Law of Total Expectation.$$\mathsf E(Z)=\mathsf E\big(\mathsf E(Z\mid Y)\big)$$

> The reasoning I've tried/heard: "We "fix" a value of $Y=y$, and calculate the expectation given assuming this is true, and then times this by the "density" and sum over all possible 
>   $y$ values.
>
> I was a little dissatisfied with this explanation because it seems to just be describing the integral.

It seems fairly intuitive.   The *expectation of a random variable* is its probability weighted average.   If we partition the support of the random variable then the expectation is the probability weighted average of the *conditional expectations* over each partition. $$\mathsf E(g(X,Y))=\sum_i\mathsf E(g(X,Y)\mid Y\in S_i)~\mathsf P(Y\in S_i)\qquad\text{where }\{S_i\}\text{ partitions the support for Y}$$

If we *carefully* make the partitions small enough, that summation approaches the integral.$$\mathsf E(g(X,Y))=\int_\Bbb R \mathsf E(g(X,Y)\mid Y=y)\,f_{\small Y}(y)\,\mathrm d y$$

$\tiny\text{[Assuming that conditional expectation is definable and that the marginal pdf exists.]}$

---

Well, when $X,Y$ are random variables with a joint probability density function, $f_{\small X,Y}$, then by the definition of expectation we have:

$$\mathsf E(g(X,Y)) =\iint_{\Bbb R^2} g(x,y)\, f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d(x,y)$$

Now by definition of conditional probability density, if the marginal and conditional density functions exist (which they *usually* do): $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(g(X,Y)) &=\iint_{\Bbb R^2} g(x,y)\, f_{\small X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,f_{\small Y}(y)\,\mathrm d(x,y)\\[2ex]&=\int_\Bbb R\left(\int_\Bbb R g(x,y)\,f_{\small X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,\mathrm d y\right)\,f_{\small Y}(y)\,\mathrm d x\end{align}$$

So... this *gives us* a definition for conditional expectation with respect to values of $Y$.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(g(X,Y)) &=\int_\Bbb R\mathsf E(g(X,Y)\mid Y{=}y)\,f_{\small Y}(y)\,\mathrm d y\\[2ex]&=\mathsf E\big(\mathsf E(g(X,Y)\mid Y)\big)\end{align}$$

Comment: Very detailed and helpful answer. Thank you so much for this!